# How to get my background photos to stay at the top?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When I view my homepage in the "portrait tablet" dimension, the background photos of my middle content are pushed down below the heading text. What CSS rules can I write so that the background photos stay up at the top when viewed in the portrait tablet mode?

To better illustrate the problem:

The problem: [image: The problem]

Intended layout: [looks like this http://www.ogmda.com/test/screen2.jpg](http://www.ogmda.com/test/screen2.jpg).

Live code for the s[ite is here](http://www.ogmda.com/test). Be sure to drag the browser corners to view it in "portrait-tablet" mode.

Comment: Much better. Nicely done. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) property allows you to control where your image appears.  You've currently got this set to `left`, meaning the image is vertically centered.  Change it to `top left` to have the image at the top left.

Change

```
background-position: left;
```

to

```
background-position: top left;
```

Answer (score 1):

In classess: .about, .beef, .map, try to change

> background-position:left

to

> background-position: 0 0;